# How to find the matrix of $dN_p: T_p S \to T_p S$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Do Carmo's Differential Geometry book. He defines the kinds of points in a surface:

> [image]

Then let's say we have the surface given by:

$$x(u,v)=\left(u,v,v^2-u^2\right)$$

The normal vector at point $p=(u,v)$ in this surface is:

$$N_p =\left(\frac{2 u}{\sqrt{4 u^2+4 v^2+1}},-\frac{2 v}{\sqrt{4 u^2+4 v^2+1}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 u^2+4
   v^2+1}}\right)$$

And I guess $dN_p$ would be:

$$dN_p=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{2}{\sqrt{4 u^2+4 v^2+1}}-\frac{8 u^2}{\left(4 u^2+4 v^2+1\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{8 u v}{\left(4
   u^2+4 v^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \\
 \frac{8 u v}{\left(4 u^2+4 v^2+1\right)^{3/2}} & \frac{8 v^2}{\left(4 u^2+4
   v^2+1\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{4 u^2+4 v^2+1}} \\
 -\frac{4 u}{\left(4 u^2+4 v^2+1\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{4 v}{\left(4 u^2+4 v^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

As $dN_p$ is a mapping from $T_p S$ to $T_p S$ and this space has dimension two, we must find a $2\times 2$ matrix so that we can actually compute the determinant given in the aforementioned definition. I am a bit confused: How do I do this?

Comment: It's in the very next section in the book, section 3.3 (Gauss map in local coordinates). I assume from the image you posted that you're currently reading section 3.2

Comment: @ElliotHerrington Yes, I'm on section 3.2.  I thought I had missed something in this section.

Comment: You should first look for a basis of $T_pS$ (consisting of two vectors) and **after that**, look at the matrix of $dN_p$ in that basis. What you gave is not the matrix of $dN_p$ in any basis of $T_pS$.